# abstraction vs abstract class

Tags: oop

according to  http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs211/2006sp/Lectures/L08-abstraction/08_abstraction.html

abstraction comes in two flavors. One is function abstraction and the other is data abstraction. But where do abstract classes fit in? As far as i see, abstract classes are a totally different concept and even though the name suggests that it has something to do with OOP principles.

Could someone please shed some light on this ?

Comment: http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0084.html.

Comment: @crowso- are you not satiesfied with the answers yet? Please accept one of the answers

Answer (score 15):

These are very different concepts.

Abstraction is similar to the concept of a black box. Input goes in, black box does something, output comes out. It doesn't matter what happens in the black box, all you have to know is that it works. A real life example of this is java's hash function, all the user has to know is that it hashes the input value, it doesn't matter to the user how the number gets hashed. The black box is the abstraction. The point is you don't have to know how it works, just that it does.

Abstract classes (at least in Java) are a mixture between interfaces and full OOP classes. An interface defines methods that any extending class must have, its an agreement in the code that it will implement the interface properly and assures everything will work as expected. An abstract class has these empty methods(agreements) and also has fully implemented methods that can be called.

Answer (score 5):

Data abstraction is a different concept from an abstract class.

Data abstraction -
It means **hiding the implementation** and showing only essential information.
Practically, we can use **access-specifiers like public, private, protected**, etc to achieve abstraction.
For eg, Private functions/variables cannot be used accessed outside the class. **Abstraction is simply 'hiding'.**
You can refer geeksforgeeks for more details.

Abstract class - Abstract classes/methods are created so that it can be **implemented in its subclasses** because the abstract class does not know what to implement in the method but it knows that the method will exist in its subclass. So, while we creating subclass we need to **override the abstract method** to provide its implementation.

Comment: Data hiding and Data abstractions are two different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in general combine data with functionality, and an abstract class is no exception to that. In some cases, the abstraction provided is almost pure data, with functions only to provide access to the data (e.g., collection classes). Other cases are nearly the opposite (e.g., the abstraction provided by a functor in C++ is typically pretty much a function).

Those, of course, are pretty much the extremes -- many (most?) classes fall somewhere between them.

Comment: yeah this is my argument. But you haven't mentioned about the abstract class and the abstract concept whether those two are same or different ?

Comment: @user581544: My point is that an abstract class *can* represent either or both to varying degrees.

Answer (score 1):

### Abstraction

When you call a method or function, you just need to know the parameters. The inner workings of the method/function are hidden from you. This is an example of **abstraction**.

Here's another example: Let's say your software architect wrote a public class `Engine` with a method `engineStart()`. You can call the `Engine.engineStart()` method anywhere on an object of `Engine`, without having to know how `engineStart()` uses quicksort as its sorting algorithm.

### Abstract Class

Let's say that your software architect wrote an abstract class `Engine` with an abstract method `engineStart()`. In any class that inherits the `Engine` class, you have to provide an implementation of the `engineStart()` method. It's a process to ensure all the child classes who inherited the engine parent class will have the `engineStart()` functionality.

Here are some relevant notes about classes:

- You can't create an object of an abstract class directly -- the abstract class's constructor cannot be invoked except inside other constructions through `super()`.
- Using a method of any class through an object is an example of  abstraction

Comment: please provide code sample also to better understanding

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, what you first got to understand is the interface. I think interface is the key to understanding the abstraction. In the article, it points out that it is very useful that having an interface between engineer.

For example:if multiple engineers are working on building a car, the engine team will design and build the engine. The gear team will just work on their gear box design. The gear box team don't need to know how the engine works. They just need to know that which part of the engine will be spinning and which button to press to turn on. They just connect it and they will continue work on their gear box. In this case, interface is just the power button to turn the engine on and the spinning part.

There are multiple benefits for this approach. It protect the incorrect use of the engine. The abstraction barrier protects the implementation. It give flexibility to the engine team. It is easier to make blame which person screw up. What I mean by is that if someone can't turn on the engine, the engine team is at fault. If someone is pressing the wrong button to turn on the engine, the gear box team is at fault or someone who is using it.