# Abstraction vs. abstract class and interfaces

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class, abstraction

I thought about reading about abstraction and I got really confused by reading different posts on it.

So, here are my questions which i'm unable able to understand:

**1)** "Is abstraction achieved through using abstract class and interface?" I have searched about this and I got three type of answers:

- Which are different like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12593984/6528991).
- They are same but are just different point of view like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443222/6528991).
- And the last one is abstract class is used to achieve abstraction like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)#Programming_languages).

**Which one is true?** With a simple example please.

---

**2)** "Abstraction means hiding unnecessary details. Like concentrating on what an object does instead of how it's done."

**Is this correct?**

---

**3)** In abstract classes we can define concrete implementation and just a method signature and we force the developer(who uses the abstract class) to write implementations on his own. So, how can it be abstraction if he is writing his own implementation? I thought abstraction is to hide the implementation. And in interfaces the developer has to write every method implementation.

**So, where does abstraction come here?**

---

**4)** The dictionary definition of Abstraction means *"the quality of dealing with ideas rather than events"* - which I think correct definition for interfaces and partially for abstract classes. But definition of abstraction in computer field/domain is *"hiding unnecessary details"*(in short).

**Am I correct in differentiating them?**

---

Please explain/answer this using examples or simple statements.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

An *abstraction* is a concept that can have one or more *implementations*.

For example: there are many different ways that your computer can connect to a local network (Ethernet, Wi-Fi, ATM, dial-up modem, etc.), but your Web browser doesn't generally have to worry about which of these you're using at any given time, because lower-level software provides a common abstraction that your browser can rely on. So "connection to the network" is the abstraction, and Ethernet and Wi-Fi and so on are implementations of that abstraction.

You'll notice that so far I haven't mentioned object-oriented programming at all. That's because the idea of implementing abstractions is common to all sorts of designs and architectures; it's not specific to OOP.

In object-oriented programming, where an implementation is likely to be represented as an object specified by a class, it's common for an abstraction to be specified by an abstract class or an interface. But this does not mean that abstract classes and interfaces are *only* for specifying abstractions, and conversely, it doesn't mean that all abstractions are specified by abstract classes and interfaces. For example, the famous Design Patterns (the singleton pattern, the factory method pattern, etc.) are all abstractions that are not explicitly specified in code; rather, we have separate (unrelated) pieces of code for the various implementations of these abstractions, and the abstraction merely resides in the programmer's head (and in design documentation, and in the names of classes and variables and so on).

> 3) In abstract classes we can define concrete implementation and just a method signature and we force the developer(who uses the abstract class) to write implementations on his own. So, how can it be abstraction if he is writing his own implementation? I thought abstraction is to hide the implementation. And in interfaces the developer has to write every method implementation.
>
> So, where does abstraction come here?

The abstraction is for *clients* (*users*) of the class. There needs to be an implementation, of course; but, for example, code that accepts a `List<String>` doesn't have to worry about whether the passed-in instance is an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, because they both implement the required abstraction.

Even when the same developer is writing both the implementation code and the client code, the separation of concerns can make it easier to maintain both parts; the implementation and the client code can both be simpler and clearer if the abstraction is well-defined and the client code never "snoops" into implementation details. (This is true even if the "abstraction" is simply expressed as Javadoc, rather than as an actual interface.)